# I can't list or see my locations from square

Tags: service, endpoint, square-connect

I have 2 locations created in my dashboard
but when I go to Apps->Locations there's nothing
only this meessage "Locations temporarily unavailable"
What could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason:
My "Personal Access Token" was for some stranger reason empty...
Just use "Replace" options and done.